# Crystal Report Time Difference Formula With Conditions

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2016

I am trying to create a report for labour effectiveness in a manufacturing business that links to 2 x distinct MS SQL databases.

"Database A" contains information about what employees were doing when they were on shift.

"Database B" contains information about what time an employee clocked in or out for payroll info.

One of the comparisons I want to report on, is the total time an employee was logged into a job vs the total time they were clocked in the building. The data is related on employee number. The main report is linked to database A and is grouped on "Employee Name", within the group footer, there is a sub report linked to Database B and the employee name is passed through as a parameter.

My problem is the way database B records clocking in. I am using a SQL command to collect the data:

```
SELECT 
tws.date_and_time
, CONVERT(date, tws.date_and_time) AS 'Date'
,te.first_name
, te.last_name
, concat(te.first_name,' ', te.last_name) AS 'ConcatName'
, CASE WHEN tws.flag IN (1,3) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as manual_adjustment
, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY tw.date_and_time ORDER BY tws.date_and_time ASC) AS swipe_number
, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY tw.date_and_time ORDER BY tws.date_and_time ASC) % 2 AS in_swipe

FROM temployee te
INNER JOIN twork tw
ON te.employee_id = tw.employee_id AND tw.type = 1000
INNER JOIN twork_swipe tws
on tw.work_id = tws.work_id
```

The "swipe_number" details what number swipe that record is in the time period (e.g. 1st, 2nd, 3rd etc.)

The "in_swipe" displays 1 if this is the employee clocking in or 0 if it employee clocking out.

I am grouping the sub report on date.

This is relatively straight forward if an employee clocks in and out once on the same day, but I am struggling to work out how to account for if an employee clocks in and out multiple times during a shift (for a break for example) or if an employee clocks in on one day and out on another (night shift for example).

I need to sum the total time an employee is clocked in, so I need to evaluate if the 1st clock of the day is an "in swipe", (swipe_number = 1 AND in_swipe = 1) if it is not, it should not be recorded as the difference between swipe_number 2 and 1, it should be from the start of the day (00:00:0000) to swipe_number = 1 as this indicates the employee has been there since midnight.

Likewise if the last (or only) "swipe_number" of the day is an "in swipe", the time should be recorded as between that time and 23:59:5999.

Outside of this, I need to find the time between the date time fields where swipe numbers = 2 & 1, 4 & 3, 6 & 5 etc. (no fixed number of times a swipe can occur).

Can this be handled dynamically in formulas?

Comment: If any given date has multiple clock_in/clock_out records, do you have a distinct value for each clock_in/clock_out pair that you could group data on?  This would allow you to put each pair of in/out times into a section that could be summed within the date grouping.  Or am I over-simplifying the problem?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is nothing that groups a pair of clock in/out values. There could be cases where there is only 1 x clock time on a specific date (If an employee is on a night shift on a Monday after weekend, they could clock in at 10pm that day).

Comment: Without a way to group the on a pair of in/out values I'm at a loss as to what to do.  Would it be possible to go to the SQL Server database and create a stored procedure that could pull the data in such a way that it creates the pairs so you could have in and out values in one row together?  When you in or out values that have no pair you could leave them NULL or default them to 00:00:01.  The complexity of doing this is going to depend upon your Db design and SQL skills.